# How can I automatically lock the screen when idle in CentOS?

Tags: javascript, c, linux, centos-5

How can I automatically lock the screen when idle in CentOS?

I would like it so that a user has to re-enter their password once the machine has been idle for a period of time.

If there is no option to do this in CentOs, what other solutions would allow me to achieve this?

Comment: What is the desktop environment you are using???? gnome????

Comment: yes,,it's GNOME...=)

Comment: You can use `xscreensaver`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this in the below link

http://ejd021-linux.blogspot.in/2011/06/how-to-lock-screen-in-centos.html

you may need to change the ftp url's to

```
wget ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/libXp-1.0.0-8.1.el5.x86_64.rpm
```

and

`wget ftp://ftp.sunet.se/pub/Linux/distributions/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/openmotif-2.3.1-7.2.el5.x86_64.rp`m

the third URL given works fine. 
Just follow the instructions on the blog and you will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Go to System -> Preferences -> Screensaver
Then change the computer idle time and enable Lock screen when screen saver is idle settings.

Comment: it doesn't work for my Cent0s 5.8,,and i want to emphasize that i'm logging in as root,,I want to login as root! =)

Answer (score 0):

try using the following commands 
Set the idle delay by replacing 1 with the delay you want. The time is in minutes.

`gconftool-2 --type int --set /desktop/gnome/session/idle_delay 1`

set the `disable_lock_screen false` to ask for password after idle time out or `disable_lock_screen true` for no password after idle timeout.

`gconftool-2 --type bool --set /desktop/gnome/lockdown/disable_lock_screen false`